# Open org-src code edit buffer automatically upon starting edit

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Editing src blocks directly in org file is nice but you cannot benefit from all minor modes that would be enabled in dedicated code edit buffer, more then that for a big babel file the performance struggles. Usually I forget to do this additional keystroke and end up editing in org. Is there any out-of-the-box option or simple workaround this can be made automatic - e.g. whenever I hit edit command the buffer is opened automatically and gets activated with all input continuing there?

p.s. I'm using evil - one thing that came to my mind was capturing some evil-into-insert-mode-hook and checking if I'm inside a src block, but this is does not cover all cases of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured that out on my own - at least, for **evil**:

```
    (add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda() 
        (make-local-variable 'evil-insert-state-entry-hook) ;; making this hook act only locally in the buffer where org-mode-hook has been called
        (add-hook 'evil-insert-state-entry-hook #'org-edit-src-code)))
```

Comment: You should be able to [accept](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) your own answer by now.